# Issue saving result of "find" function in a shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm pretty new to shell scripting, but it's been great in helping me automating cumbersome tasks in OS X.

One of the functions I'm trying to write in a new script needs to find the specific filename in a subdirectory given a regex string. While I do know that the file exists, the version (and therefore filename itself) is being continually updated.

My function is currently as follows:

```
fname(){
  $2=$(find ./Folder1 -name "$1*NEW*")
}
```

Which I'm then calling later in my script with the following line:

```
fname Type1 filename1
```

What I'm hoping to do is save the filename I'm looking for in variable filename1. My find syntax seems to be correct if I run it in Terminal, but I get the following error when I run my script:

```
./myscript.sh: line 13: filename1=./Folder1/Type1-list-NEW.bin: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure why the result of find is not just saving to the variable I've selected. I'd appreciate any help (regardless of trivial this question may end up being). Thanks!

EDIT: I have a bunch of files in the subdirectory, but with the way I'm setting that folder up I know my "find" query will return exactly 1 filename. I just need the specific filename to do various tasks (updating, version checking, etc.)

Comment: If any file name has white space in it, this approach is likely to give you headaches.  What do you ultimately  want to do with your variable `filename1`?  Is there a good reason that you are using a variable to store filenames and not an array?

Comment: I'll edit my question, but since I'm using this for automation I know that I'll only have a single file in "Folder1" that matches the specified regex.

Comment: OK.  Also: (1)  `-name` does not match a _regex_; it matches a _glob_.  regexes and glob follow very different rules.  (2) Is there a reason why you require this syntax `fname Type1 filename1`?  In shell, it would be much more natural, avoiding use of the dangerous `eval`, to use the syntax `filename1=$(fname Type1)`

Comment: John, good to know that it's `glob` and not `regex`. And yes, I've adjusted my function so that I'm not using `eval` but instead using the `$()` method. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for writing output to a file is `command > filename`. So it should be:

```
fname() {
    find ./Folder1 -name "$1*NEW*" > "$2"
}
```

`=` is for assigning to a variable, not saving output in a file.

Are you sure you need to put the output in a file? Why not put it in a variable:

```
fname() {
    find ./Folder1 -name "$1*NEW*"
}

var=$(fname Type1)
```

If you really want the function to take the variable name as a parameter, you have to use `eval`

```
fname() {
    eval "$2='$(find ./Folder1 -name "$1*NEW*")'"
}
```

Comment: I actually am trying to save to a variable (that's what $2 is supposed to be). So my syntax there is wrong then?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to use `eval` to assign to a variable whose name is in a parameter.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! I implemented the second code block, but the third one is good to know. I didn't realize I couldn't save to a passed variable name (I was thinking it might work like a pointer).

Comment: Instead of `eval`, `bash` builtin printf can do the trick `printf -v $2 "%s " $(find ./Folder1 -name "$1*NEW*")`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I'm reading this as, you want to take the output of the find and save it in a shell variable given by `$2`.

You can't actually use a shell variable to dynamically declare the name of a new shell variable to rename, when the shell sees an expansion at the beginning of a line it immediately begins processing the words as arguments and not as an assignment.

There might be some way of pulling this off with `declare` and `export` but generally speaking you don't want to use a shell variable to hold *n* file names, particularly if you're on OS X, those file names probably have whitespaces and you're not protecting for that in the way your find is outputting.

Generally what you do in this case is you take the list of files `find` is spitting out and you act on them immediately, either with `find -exec` or as a part of a `find . -print0 | xargs -0` pipeline.

Comment: Thanks iluvcapra! "You can't actually use a shell variable to dynamically declare the name of a new shell variable". I didn't know this, so that makes sense now why it wasn't working.

Comment: OTOH I wasn't aware of the `eval` trick, that might work but you're still going to run into trouble because your call of `find` isn't returning paths in a way that another program can split them apart again.